# need to put repeating XML nodes in separate nodes with the help of xsl / xslt

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this xml:

```
<products>
 <product>
 <name>ad</name>
 <category>something</category>
 <path>something</path>
    <size>S</size>
    <color-code>87-3</color-code>
    <size-code>24294</size-code>
    <size-qty>10</size-qty>
    <size-codeproducer>5902228002604</size-codeproducer>
    <size>M</size>
    <color-code>87-4</color-code>
    <size-code>24295</size-code>
    <size-qty>64</size-qty>
    <size-codeproducer>5902228002611</size-codeproducer>
    <size>L</size>
    <color-code>87-5</color-code>
    <size-code>24296</size-code>
    <size-qty>46</size-qty>
    <size-codeproducer>5902228002628</size-codeproducer>
    <size>XXL</size>
    <color-code>87-7</color-code>
    <size-code>24298</size-code>
    <size-qty>0</size-qty>
    <size-codeproducer>5902228002635</size-codeproducer>
    <imgs>
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_2.jpg</img>
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_1.jpg</img>
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_4.jpg</img>
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_5.jpg</img>
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_3.jpg</img>
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_6.jpg</img>
    </imgs>google.com</url>
    <price>7.98</price>
    <brand>NIKE</brand>
    <color>black</color>
    <gender>Man</gender>
  </product>
  <product>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  </product>
</products>
```

what I need:

```
<products>
<product>
<name>ad</name>
<category>something</category>
...
<variation>
   <size>S</size>
   <color-code>87-3</color-code>
   <size-code>24294</size-code>
   <size-qty>10</size-qty>
   <size-codeproducer>5902228002604</size-codeproducer>
</variation>
<variation>
   <size>M</size>
   <color-code>87-4</color-code>
   <size-code>24295</size-code>
   <size-qty>64</size-qty>
   <size-codeproducer>5902228002611</size-codeproducer>
</variation>
<variation>
   <size>L</size>
   <color-code>87-5</color-code>
   <size-code>24296</size-code>
   <size-qty>46</size-qty>
   <size-codeproducer>5902228002628</size-codeproducer>
</variation>
<variation>
   <size>XXL</size>
   <color-code>87-7</color-code>
   <size-code>24298</size-code>
   <size-qty>0</size-qty>
   <size-codeproducer>5902228002635</size-codeproducer>
</variation>
</product>
<product>
...
</product>
</products>
```

I have this xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="/products/product">

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="description|id|name|category|path"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/products/product/size">
                <variation>
                    <xsl:variable name="occur" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/products/product/color-code[$occur]"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/products/product/size-code[$occur]"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/products/product/size-qty[$occur]"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/products/product/size-codeproducer[$occur]"/>
                </variation>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="imgs|url|price|brand|color|gender"/>
        </xsl:copy>

     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the results are an xml file that copies
`size-codeproducer`,`color-code`,`size-code` and `size-qty` in every product node.
any help would be appreciated.

I've tried various variations of xsl copying - for-each loops and other things, but most of them didn't print anything after parsing, printed the same document or there were other problems. I'm guessing the problem is the paths(xpaths?) I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to show another approach to grouping adjacents or starting with something in XSLT 1.0, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="shallow-copy">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="size">
     <variation>
      <xsl:call-template name="group-starting-with"/>
     </variation>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="color-code|size-code|size-qty|size-codeproducer">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="group-starting-with"
      name="group-starting-with">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" 
       mode="group-starting-with"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="size|imgs" mode="group-starting-with"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<products> 
  <product> 
    <name>ad</name>  
    <category>something</category>  
    <path>something</path>  
    <variation> 
      <size>S</size>  
      <color-code>87-3</color-code>  
      <size-code>24294</size-code>  
      <size-qty>10</size-qty>  
      <size-codeproducer>5902228002604</size-codeproducer> 
    </variation>  
    <variation> 
      <size>M</size>  
      <color-code>87-4</color-code>  
      <size-code>24295</size-code>  
      <size-qty>64</size-qty>  
      <size-codeproducer>5902228002611</size-codeproducer> 
    </variation>  
    <variation> 
      <size>L</size>  
      <color-code>87-5</color-code>  
      <size-code>24296</size-code>  
      <size-qty>46</size-qty>  
      <size-codeproducer>5902228002628</size-codeproducer> 
    </variation>  
    <variation> 
      <size>XXL</size>  
      <color-code>87-7</color-code>  
      <size-code>24298</size-code>  
      <size-qty>0</size-qty>  
      <size-codeproducer>5902228002635</size-codeproducer> 
    </variation>  
    <imgs> 
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_2.jpg</img>  
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_1.jpg</img>  
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_4.jpg</img>  
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_5.jpg</img>  
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_3.jpg</img>  
      <img>pictures/large/7/8/87_6.jpg</img> 
    </imgs>  
    <url>google.com</url>  
    <price>7.98</price>  
    <brand>NIKE</brand>  
    <color>black</color>  
    <gender>Man</gender> 
  </product>  
  <product>... ... ...</product> 
</products>
```

**Do note**: this is traversing in the following axe. It means that every rule is responsible of applying templates to first child and first following sibling. For grouping you need a rule with the matching criterion to start, empty rules to stop at not matching criterion, and bypass rules when the criterion is matched but you are not grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you have a problem with your `xsl:for-each`...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/products/product/size">
```

By starting the select expression with a `/`, which represents the document node, you are effectively doing an absolute search, and ignoring the `product` you are currently positioned on. You should just do this, to get the `size` elements for the current product

```
<xsl:for-each select="size">
```

And similarly, for the various `xsl:copy-of` statements, instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/products/product/color-code[$occur]"/>
```

You should do this (where `..` gets the parent of the current `size` element)

```
<xsl:copy-of select="../color-code[$occur]"/>
```

Try this template instead

```
 <xsl:template match="/products/product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="description|id|name|category|path"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="size">
            <variation>
                <xsl:variable name="occur" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../color-code[$occur]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../size-code[$occur]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../size-qty[$occur]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../size-codeproducer[$occur]"/>
            </variation>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="imgs|url|price|brand|color|gender"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

(Note you could also do `<xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::color-code[1]"/>` here, and similarly for the other statements).